# NSolve for complicated equation involving double cross product

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I have the following issue. I am trying to solve a 3-vector equation for the vector `slx`, `sly`, and `slz` as below. The vector of `sl` enters in a very complex manner so I was hoping to use `NSolve`. There is a term involving a single cross-product and another involving a double cross-product. The double cross-product term is giving me problems - e.g. I have not been able to wait long enough for a solution to pop out. The single cross-product seems to pose no problem whatsoever. I suppose the double cross-product term possesses higher orders of `sl` that are the issue.

Is there anyway the code below can be vastly sped up?

```
Off[NSolve::ratnz] (*Turn off annoying warning when using \
NSolve...can probably be addressed by using Rationalize[]*)
sl = {slx, sly, slz};
(* electron charge *) e = 1.602176565`*^-19;
(* electron mass *) me = 9.10938291`*^-31;
\[Gamma] = -0.44 e/(2 me) 10^-9/10^4 ;
bn = -5000. ;
be = -2. ;
BL = 20. ;
\[Tau]0 = 2.; \[Tau]n = 6.; k0 = 5.; kn = 10.;
G = 0.08;
sol[B_List] := NSolve[{
{0, 0, 0} == -(k0/(k0 + kn) *1/\[Tau]n + k0/(k0 + kn) *1/\[Tau]0) sl + \[Gamma] Cross[B + bn  (((B + be sl).sl) (B + be sl))/((B + be sl).(B + be sl) + 
BL^2), sl] - \[Gamma]^2 1/(k0 + kn) Cross[bn (((B + be sl).sl) (B + be sl))/((B + be sl).(B + be sl) + BL^2), Cross[sl, 
     bn (((B + be sl).sl) (B + be sl))/((B + be sl).(B + be sl) + 
       BL^2)]] + G {1, 0, 0}}, sl, Reals] // Flatten

sol[{100. Sin[0 Degree], 0, 100. Cos[0 Degree]}]
```

has not outputted in the time I have entered this cell.

However it returns quickly when the double cross product term is negated:

> ```
> {slx -> 0.0854324, sly -> -0.153157, slz -> 0}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

If you are not too concerned about the possibility of denominators vanishing, could remove them first. The `Numerator[Together[...]]` below is for that purpose. It might also be better to use exact input since `Together` and approximate numbers do not always play nice together. But in this case it seems to work out. Your example then runs to completion in a minute and a half or so.

```
sl = {slx, sly, slz};
(*electron charge*)e = 1.602176565`*^-19;
(*electron mass*)me = 9.10938291`*^-31;
\[Gamma] = -0.44 e/(2 me) 10^-9/10^4;
bn = -5000;
be = -2;
BL = 20;
\[Tau]0 = 2; \[Tau]n = 6; k0 = 5; kn = 10;
G = 8/100;
sol[B_List] := 
 NSolve[Numerator[
   Together[-(k0/(k0 + kn)*1/\[Tau]n + 
         k0/(k0 + kn)*1/\[Tau]0) sl + \[Gamma] Cross[
       B + bn (((B + be sl).sl) (B + 
              be sl))/((B + be sl).(B + be sl) + BL^2), 
       sl] - \[Gamma]^2 1/(k0 + kn) *
      Cross[bn (((B + be sl).sl) (B + 
             be sl))/((B + be sl).(B + be sl) + BL^2), 
       Cross[sl, 
        bn (((B + be sl).sl) (B + be sl))/((B + be sl).(B + be sl) + 
            BL^2)]] + G {1, 0, 0}]], sl, Reals]

Timing[sol[{100 Sin[0 Degree], 0, 100 Cos[0 Degree]}]]
```

> ```
> {87.308000, {{slx -> 0.0854340416823, sly -> -0.153153750824,
>         slz -> -2.41627183645*10^-8}, {slx -> 0.0854340416823, 
>        sly -> -0.153153750824, 
>        slz -> -2.41627183645*10^-8}, {slx -> 0.0854340416823, 
>        sly -> -0.153153750824, slz -> -2.41627183645*10^-8}}}
> ```